# router-ui re resolve dependencies not working (angularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, resolve

i already read a ton of posts about this topic but none of them seem to work for me. Am I doing something wrong?

I am using router with a lot of states like this one:

```
$stateProvider.
            state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController',
                resolve: {
                    'Session': function (accountService) {
                        return accountService.pullSession;
                    }
                }
            }).
```

the 'pull' are all something like this

```
pullSession: $http.get('api/session').success(function (data) {
    classes = data;
}),
```

The problem is that every time I do login / logout and I change state the session is not pulled again and some other resources that are session dependant that were pulled already are not pulled again.

So I have tried almost every think with reload:true like

```
$state.go('newstate', {reload:true});
and <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Home</a>
```

and nothing seems to work. For now I am doing

```
$window.location.reload()
```

which does forces all the page to reload but that is not very efficient.

So , can you see what am I doing wrong? what should I be doing?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your $http in pullSession.

`pullSession: $http.get('api/session').success(function (data) {
    classes = data;
    return classes;
}),`

Comment: did that. does not work. The first time the controller loads, all the dependencies are load too but if i change state/controller (i.e. when login) session dependency is not called again.

Comment: Looking at your code snippet more, where you are deciding how to reload you are using states names 'home' and 'newstate' - the resolve is only for the state login, so those would not work.

Comment: Oh, i only posted a bit of my code here but i have that resolve 'session' in each state. 
I'm afraid i'm making some confusion. Is it supposed to work? i mean, when i change state, all the dependencies be resolved again?